# ionic update-notifier-cordova.json' You don't have access to this file

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run ionic on iOS, but it throws an error.

What happened?

```
ionic run ios
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                    throw err;
                          ^
    Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/jiahongl/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
    You don't have access to this file.

        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:352:15)
        at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
        at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
        at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
        at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
        at checkForUpdates (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:64:20)
        at cli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:114:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:41:1)
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo52o.png)

Comment: Pass the error message into the question rather than giving it as image.... error "Permssion Denied".....

Answer (score 32):

I just changed permission of the file `update-notifier-cordova.json` by below command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 '/Users/anand.d.gupta/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
```

And this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 23):

delete the file **update-notifier-cordova.json** from this location  problem solved, it's nothing but just a config file

Comment: @danm07 first you should install npm

Comment: Had a corrupted npm while I was reconfiguring. This did work, I upvoted.

Comment: The file gets recreated with the same bad permissions. So the top answer fixed that for me

Answer (score 12):

Deleting the file wont be a right option, the following approach worked out for me.  The root cause of this issue is because of the Cordova-cli permissions.

**Step 1:** Uninstallcordova and install it again.

```
 sudo npm remove -g cordova
```

**Step 2:** Install with the following command

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true cordova
```

Make sure it installs the recent version, by typing `$ ionic info` you can see the Cordova CLI versions

**Step 3:** Secure the permissions for the following folders

```
sudo chown -R <username> /Users/<username>/.config/configstore/
sudo chown -R <username> /Users/<username>/.cordova/

ionic build ios  - Should work like charm
```

Answer (score 8):

In my project, this problem has been fixed with this lines:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```

Answer (score 6):

changed permission to this folder

```
sudo chown -R yourusername /Users/yourusername/.config/configstore/
```