# (Ionic 2) An Error occurred trying to fall back to Cordova-lib execution: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Edit:** This is happening when working with ionic 2. I know it's not stable yet, but i assume that there may be some fix for this, since it seems like others don't get this problem. **Edit end**

For some reason i've suddenly started to get this error when trying to build my ionic app, using "ionic build android", and also "ionic build ios":

```
An Error occurred trying to fall back to Cordova-lib execution: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.IonicTask.runCordova (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:262:21)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:142:19
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:430:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:13)

Error happened [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.IonicTask.runCordova (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:262:21)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:142:19
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:430:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:13)
```

I'm lost here, and have no idea where to start looking.

Is there anyone who has seen this before, and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you put your code snippet in plunker or stack overflow to get an idea about what you are asking @larschla

Comment: @Anilkumar The problem here is that it doesn't seem to be my code that does anything. I get this error every time i try to run

    **ionic build android**

It makes no difference which of my apps i do it on. It seems like the whole ionic build thing is broken.

Comment: I've tried to reinstall ionic and cordova, without any luck. 

It is possible to build both android and ios if i run ionic build android as administrator (sudo). The problem then is that the output from the build needs to be chmod/chown every time i want to do anything with them. E.g. open the ios project in xcode.

So, it seems like it's a permission issue - i just don't know what files/folders i need to give the right premissions.

Comment: Can you please tell me the Operating System which you are using@larschla

Comment: I'm currently on OS X El Capitan @Anilkumar

Comment: The above error seem's to be issue in your project only but not with libraries I think, I am 100% sure, Can you do 1 thing , please create a sample project and try with ionic build android or ionic build ios @larschla

Comment: @Anilkumar: I just did. 
**ionic start testapp**
then i cd into the testapp folder, and ran **ionic build ios**. Same error as before.

Comment: can you please type `ionic info` and paste the output here@larschla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101187/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-larschla).

Answer (score 6):

@mabs @mgcdanny

I am pretty certain I've figured out the root cause to the issue.  I ran `cordova -v` and saw this output -

```
Ross-MBP:test rossmartin$ cordova -v
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/rossmartin/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

I then ran

```
Ross-MBP:test rossmartin$ sudo chown -R rossmartin ~/.config
Ross-MBP:test rossmartin$ cordova -v
6.0.0
```

Now I see cordova reporting it is at 6.0.0 and can do ionic build/prepare again.

I think what happened is that the Ionic CLI did not think that the cordova CLI was installed.  Maybe it is possible that somewhere the Ionic CLI does a `cordova -v` and was getting hung up by the permission issue reading the `~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json` file.

Comment: Same config (El Capitan) and was in the dark for more than 4 hours. It solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: This was the fix for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu.

I needed to install a few dependencies.

Firstly cordova, with:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

The Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

And a Java SDK.

Comment: Same on windows.. `npm install -g cordova` did the trick for me

Comment: I just get 'throw new TypeError('invalid data');' now

Answer (score 3):

uninstall globally  (use sudo if needed)

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic@beta
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
```

fix permissions like this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

this worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

reinstall (without sudo)

```
npm install -g ionic
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you say here, but i've still got the same problem. Same error message :/

Comment: I also had to run: npm install cordova.  Additionally, I had a permission error that I solved with the answer from Anand here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812158/ionic-update-notifier-cordova-json-you-dont-have-access-to-this-file

Answer (score 0):

The build process was looking for Cordova-lib and could not find it.
This is usually caused if you have not installed Cordoval-CLI

To check if you have cordova-CLI installed, type `$ ionic info`
Check the result. if you see *Cordova CLI: Not installed*  run
*npm install -g cordova@4.2.0*
`$ ionic info` > it should show Cordova CLI: 4.2.0