# Use Ionic + Cordova to build an Ubuntu App

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, desktop-application, ionic2

I would like to use Ionic/Cordova to build an Ubuntu App. I know I can just add the platform using the command line:

```
ionic platform add ubuntu
```

But when I try to build I am getting an error and no possible way to solve the issue:

An Error occurred trying to fall back to Cordova-lib execution: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.IonicTask.runCordova (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:261:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:127:19
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Error happened TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.IonicTask.runCordova (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:261:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:127:19
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.IonicTask.runCordova (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:261:21)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/ionic/cordova.js:127:19
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Any help, please?

Comment: Is that even possible? Iv'e never heard of such usage in Ionic, Ionic is firmly designed for hybrid mobile development. Have you heard about [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)?

Comment: may [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058245/ionic-2-an-error-occurred-trying-to-fall-back-to-cordova-lib-execution-typeer) help

Comment: Thank you for your help. Well, I think Cordova gives you the possibility, so, why not? :S

Comment: It works! I just needed to install Cordova CLI! Thank you for your help!